# Mapbox Map not showing up with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mapbox

I am trying to add a map to one of rails pages using Mapbox. I followed the documentation exactly as stated on the [Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/) page, but the page fails to show up on my page.

Here's my [map](https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/morales257.opbj9hf9/page.html?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibW9yYWxlczI1NyIsImEiOiJjaWpybXdsMWMwY2tndG9tNXB5ajFhbjE3In0.whDnBZvQN5wQ5bwvtw2fBw#3/0.00/0.00).

This is the code on my index.html.erb page:

```
<div class="properties-results">
<h1>Recent Sales Near <%= params[:search] %></h1>

<div id='map'></div>
<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibW9yYWxlczI1NyIsImEiOiJjaWpybXdsMWMwY2tndG9tNXB5ajFhbjE3In0.whDnBZvQN5wQ5bwvtw2fBw';
L.mapbox.map('map', 'morales257.opbj9hf9').setView([-79.392524,43.654967], 5);

</script>
<ul>
  <% @comps.each do |comparable|%>
  <li><%= comparable.street %></li>
  <i> <%= comparable.sold_price%></i>
  <% end %>
</ul>



</div>
```

And this is the header in the application.html.erb page:

```
<head>
  <title>Workspace</title>

<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.4/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.2.4/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

From my understanding this should be enough to at least SHOW a map on the page, but nothing is coming up.

If you are familiar with Mapbox and Rails, your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfamiliar with Rails but as far as i can see, your code looks just fine. The only thing that's missing are the CSS rules for your map's containing element which can account for the map not being visible without throwing any errors to your console:

```
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

See this basic example on the Mapbox site: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/

Comment: Thanks iH8! cant believe it was something so simple as missing CSS